# When downloading files Firefox opens a terminal

Tags: firefox

When I try to download any file using my Firefox browser, it opens a terminal and downloads from there.

I don't wanna do that. Is there any way to get rid of downloading files over terminal?

I'm using ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: on the terminal it shows this:

URL 1/1...
--2016-02-10 05:53:40--  http://www.seedpeer.eu/download/us_billboard_top_100_single_charts_2nd_january_2016/89b07c8811fa29c760548eb6f0b9788a099165e7
Resolving www.seedpeer.eu (www.seedpeer.eu)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.seedpeer.eu’
Press [ENTER] to quit...

Comment: I need your idea guys, I dont want to download files on terminal.  A million thanks to somebody who can help me on this issue.

Comment: possibly flashgot or other addon was installed which switched the  downloader from the default to one running in terminal (like wget, aria2, axel)